# Data transferring

Tags: sql-server, database-design, migration

Is there any practices to transfer data from two databases that have different structure of table ?

For example :

```
old system : table [folder] with col: FolderId, name, age, sexe, date, orders 

New system : table folder 

   split to : 
             table patient with col :PatientID, name, age, sexe 
             table folder with col : PatientId, date, orders
```

We have changed the table structure but we want to recover old data 
is there any practice for that

Comment: What database platform? Are they both the same? Are they on the same server?  How big are the db's?

Comment: same server and same database platform(sql server) the db  has 39  tables

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is data migration.

To do this successfully you need to understand both the old data and new schemas, business rules and the data itself.

To migrate the data the most common option is to write conversion scripts which insert data into the new schema that respect the new schemas rules, referential integrity and business logic.

If your old data isnt a perfect match for the new schema you may lose data, or you may have to fabricate data to fullfil the new schemas requirements.

Data migration can be complex and time consuming and requires testing in a safe environment.

The right tool for the jobs depends on several things like how often you expect to do this. Is it a "one-off" or will you be repeating this many times for customers?

Edit: Given comments below. I'd import the data into a separate db on same server. Id then write sql scripts which insert into new tables. Id probably use a staging data base that has a copy if the new schema to ensure i met all of the constraints and data type rules. After i had tested that and was happy I would insert each table into the target. The order that you migrate each table will be important because of parent/child relationships.

Queries could be as simple as:

Insert targetdb.target_table (fieldA, fieldB)
Select field1, field2
From sourcedb.source_table